# How to do pop operation in javascript when unchecked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have just the two checkbox whose codes looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of documents">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.docId}}" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" [name]="item.docName"
   (change)="editPartyRolesSubmit($event)"
   />
   <span innerHTML="{{item.docName}}"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Here i have only used two checkbox as:
[image]

The function **editPartyRolesSubmit($event)** called is:

```
public documents: Array<Document> = []
public onlyTruedocuments: Array<Document> = [];

    editPartyRolesSubmit(event) {

      this.documents.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => {
        console.log("entered in check");
        this.onlyTruedocuments.push(x);
          console.log(x);
        })
    }
```

The Json data is pushed three times as it should be only pushed two times though i have just clicked two times.

[image]

But when i print them in the .html page then though the checkbox is two,It is printed three times :

```
<li *ngFor="let ot of onlyTruedocuments; index as i">

     {{ot.docName}}
</li>
```

It is printing like this:

[image]

How can i remove this redundant data?

Comment: @aswin I have added an answer and working demo along with it! Have a look at:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would do in this way,

I have used `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`

I have passed the current `item` to the `ngModelChange` function.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of documents">
    <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.docId}}" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" [name]="item.docName"
   (ngModelChange)="editPartyRolesSubmit($event,item)"/> // will pass an item to the function 
   <span innerHTML="{{item.docName}}"></span>
   </label>
</div>

<li *ngFor="let ot of onlyTruedocuments; index as i">
     {{ot.docName}}
</li>
```

TS file:

```
export class YourComponent {
  documents = [{
    docId: 1,
    checked: false,
    docName: 'Prashant'

  },
  {
    docId: 2,
    checked: false,
    docName: 'Venkat'

  }
    , {
    docId: 2,
    checked: false,
    docName: 'Perry'

  }];

  public onlyTruedocuments: any = [];

  editPartyRolesSubmit(event, obj) {
    // Take the index of an Item checked
    let index = this.onlyTruedocuments.indexOf(obj);

    // Check for event i.e it is checked or unchecked
    if (event) {
      if (index == -1) {
        // If the index is -1 then that means its not a duplicate so push into an array
        this.onlyTruedocuments.push(obj);
      }
    }
    else {
      // If it is unchecked then we surely know that the item has to be removed from the array so by an index of the particular item we can [splice][1] the item
      this.onlyTruedocuments.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

No need to filter the source array to get the checked items.

A Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5clpb) Example with Sample data.

Comment: amazing thnk u alot brother :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a unique check before you push to `onlyTruedocuments`. This way even when user click many times the object would still have unique values as expected.

```
editPartyRolesSubmit(event) {
    this.documents.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => {
    console.log("entered in check");
    const exists = this.onlyTruedocuments.filter((f)=>f.docId == x.docId);
    if(exists.length==0){
       this.onlyTruedocuments.push(x);
    }
      console.log(x);
    })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to collect unique elements only is to define `this.onlyTruedocuments` not as an array, but as a  `Set`, initialised as:

```
this.onlyTrueDocuments = new Set();
```

Then in the event handler do:

```
editPartyRolesSubmit(event) {
    this.documents.forEach(x => x.checked && this.onlyTruedocuments.add(x));
    console.log([...this.onlyTrueDocuments]); // Use spread syntax to get converson to array 
}
```